# What does Google provide web designers with?

Tags: website-design, fonts, resource-recommendations, google

I'm quite new to web-design, being primarily focused on web programming on server-side. I usually power my apps with twitter-bootstrap, using the myriad css classes it provides and I don't interfere with its work!

However, I was visiting a random blog today (http://blog.plobo.net/) and liked the fonts used very much. I used Firebug to find that the font is a WOFF font sourced from the "googleusercontent.com" domain.

Two questions:

1. Can I incorporate such fonts in my own bootstrap based app or blog?
2. Apart from this font, what all other features does this service (googleusercontent.com) provides? Does it provide social icons, logos, etc. that web designers use considerably?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google fonts:

http://www.google.com/fonts

Google fonts is an ever-growing repository of hosted open-source typefaces you can use on your web site.

Being open source, as well as hosted, it's incredibly easy to use them.

It's not a particular service, rather it's just of one of many, many things google provides web developers and designers. Creating a list of all of them is likely impractical and off topic here, but it includes things such as acting as a CDN for common libraries (such as jQuery), providing back end tools (such as the Google App Engine), and even things like being able to integrate Google Documents into your web site (such as using a Google spreadsheet as a poor-man's database for your site).